# 2D line rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transformation, rotations

[image]

I am trying to solve a sample question.
I think the answer for this is "a", but I am not sure.

I wonder if my answer is correct, what is correct answer? and I need explaination.

Comment: Could you explain what the different options mean? What do the functions represent?

Comment: Why do you think the answer is (a)? If you’re not simply guessing, explain your reasoning.